# Can anybody tell me why this linq query won't work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious, I've been coding for a lot of hours in a row and my brain is crawling to a halt.  I have the following statement:

```
var hcn = "";
var forename = "";
var surname = "";

foreach (var casenoteResult in casenoteResults)
{
    personResults.AddRange(_ctx.People.Where
        (x => x.PAS_INT_NO == casenoteResult.PAS_INT_NO 
        && x.CSA_NO.Contains(hcn) 
        && x.FORENAMES.ToLower().Contains(forename.ToLower()) 
        && x.SURNAME.ToLower().Contains(surname.ToLower()))
        .ToList());
}
```

And I get no result.  The only thing I'm really looking for is the casenote.  Yet if I comment out each of the '&&'s, so I'm left with this:

```
foreach (var casenoteResult in casenoteResults)
{
    personResults.AddRange(_ctx.People.Where
        (x => x.PAS_INT_NO == casenoteResult.PAS_INT_NO)
        .ToList());
}
```

I get 1 result, which is what I'm expected.

Can anyone help me?  Why does the first statement not return this 1 result?  Could it be that some of the fields that I'm comparing the empty strings to are null?  The one record that gets found doesn't have any nulls in it.  I'm lost here. Please help my poor battered brain!

Comment: Why did you use Contains()? Why did you not using == sign?

Comment: Because hcn, forename and surname may be more than just an empty string and I want a wildcard search against them if they do have something in then.

Comment: `I get 1 result, which is what I'm expected.` What is the `CSA_NO`, `FORENAMES` and `SURNAME` of that object?

Comment: Are any of `FORENAMES`, `CSA_NO`, or `SURNAME` null in the one result you get?

Comment: can you give the result of the correct 1 result with the no `&&` because as @JonathonK metioned, their maybe null or empty strings in the result

Comment: The result that got one has no null or empty strings, the fields of csa_no, forename and surname are all populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would re-write this code like below. It's safer to build the queryable in parts to make sure you have a good handle on which values you are actually passing in to the query. The reason why you are not getting any rows is probably because the query values going in to the query is not what you think they are or your database doesn't treat empty string as a wildcard. (Because based on what you posted, you are checking if a string contains an empty string which is always true in C# but may not be true for your database provider).

```
var queryable = _ctx.People.Where(w => caseNoteResults.Select(s => s.PAS_INT_NO).Contains(w.PAS_INT_NO));

queryable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(hcn) ? queryable : queryable.Where(w => w.CSA_NO.Contains(hcn, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));

queryable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(forename) ? queryable : queryable.Where(w => w.FORENAMES.Contains(forename, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

queryable = string.IsNullOrEmpty(surname) ? queryable : queryable.Where(w => w.SURNAME.Contains(surname, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

personResults.AddRange(queryable.ToList());
```

The idea is, if your `hcn`, `forename` and `surname` are empty, no point in checking them.

Also, make sure that you handle nulls safely if each of these fields are nullable.

Comment: I'll try it this way.  I always thought that if you do a contains with an empty string it would just bring back everything.  I'm trying to have a search where there may or may not be data in those 4 fields, and account for that in the most efficient way possible.  So when the user submits the form and any of those fields are null, I make those fields = "" which I thought would cover what I want.  Maybe I just need to rethink how I'm doing this search. ..